# how to fetch the browser set language and use in our java application.?

Tags: java, browser

I want to fetch the browser set language and want to use this language in my java application while loading the my application on the browser. While loading the application application should use the browser language, if I set the browser language in japanese, application should detect the set browser language and open my application in japanese language.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to check your request if you have the header `Accept-Language` with the value `en`, `fr`, `es`.. etc. Usually, if you use the `fetch` function in Javascript, the header is automatically here.
Then, in your Java application, you can use the HttpServletRequest class to get headers from your HTTP request.

```
private String getAcceptLanguage(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
    }
```

Comment: Once I get the header what should I fo next.?